# Linq groupby on values of List of dictionary<string,string> with unknown number of keys or key names

Tags: c#, linq

This is something I have spent several hours on and haven't been able to figure it out. Basically, I have a `List<object>`, and each object in that list has a `Dictionary<long, Dictionary<string,string>>`. The `Dictionary<string,string>` is data pair sets that need to be grouped by. Is there a way with linq to iterate through the `List<object>` with an unknown number/name of `Dictionary<string,string>` keys and use group by?

Each dictionary is actually a row of data, and the string key value pair is actually column/data, for context. And unfortunately, I cannot change how I am receiving this data.

Most of the examples I can find only seem to work with DataTables, or are hard coded for certain column names. If it is not possible while the dictionaries are inside objects in that list, can it be done if it was just a `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` ?

For the purpose of this code snippet please assume that the variable AllDataList is the complete list of ContainerClass objects. The routine Projection was borrowed from:
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/141367/Dynamic-Columns-from-List-using-LINQ

Lastly, unfortunately I cannot bring in third party library's for this.

```
public class ContainerClass
{ 
    public Dictionary<long, Dictionary<string, string>> data;

    public ContainerClass()
    {
        data = Dictionary<long, Dictionary<string, string>>;
        data.add(0,new Dictionary<string,string>());
    }
}

private dynamic Projection(object a, IEnumerable<string> props)
{
        if (a == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        IDictionary<string, object> res = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
        var type = a.GetType();

        foreach (var pair in props.Select(n => new {
            Name = n,
            Property = type.GetProperty(n)
        }))
        {
            res[pair.Name] = pair.Property.GetValue(a, new object[0]);
        }

        return res;
}

public void DoStuff()
{
    List<string> cols = new List<string>();

    //normally cols would be determined at runtime
    cols.add("Column1");
    cols.add("Column2");
    cols.add("Column3");

    List<ContainerClass> res  = (List<ContainerClass>) this.AllDataList.GroupBy(x => new[] {
 Projection(x.data,cols)
 }).Select(y =>Projection(y, cols)); //unsure if the select is necessary
}
```

**EDIT: We ended up pursuing a different route**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question perfectly, but seems to me you don't need the dynamic code (`Projection()`) at all. You just need to implement your own `IEqualityComparer<T>` by deriving new class from `EqualityComparer<Dictionary<long, Dictionary<string, string>>>` and then pass this comparer to the `.GroupBy(x => x.data, new MyEqualityComparer())` method.

Comment: This sounds like it might actually work, do you have an example of this? Basically, the Dictionary<string,string> under the first dictionary is what needs to be worked with. Since the incoming data can be hundreds of thousands items deep in the list, avoiding transforming the data would be preferable. the Dictionary<string,string> is actually a datarow, and the key is the column name, and the value is the data. I need to be able to group by on the data in each "row" (or dictionary<string,string>).

Comment: There can be multiple "rows" (Dictionary<string,string>) in each Dictionary<long,Dictionary<string,string>> though. The overall data is a List<object>, with the object having a property that is a Dictionary<long,Dictionary<string,string>> ... I hope this makes sense.

Comment: It starts making sense to me, but i still don't understand two things: *1)* You want to group 
items in `List<ContainerClass>` by `Dictionary<string,string>` (i.e. "row"), right? But each `ContainerClass` can contain multiple "rows" (`Dictionary<long, Dictionary<string, string>>`), how do you know which one of them to use as a key?  *2)*. Does all `Dictionary<string,string>` contain the same keys (i.e. "column names"), or can they be different? Maybe you could provide some small example of input data and expected output that would probably explained it better than abstract description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have something like this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(long));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "abc", "mno" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "def", "mnp" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "def", "mnq" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "abc", "mnr" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "abd", "mns" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "abe", "mnt" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "abf", "mnu" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "abc", "mnv" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "ade", "mnw" });


            Dictionary<long, Dictionary<string, string>> dict = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<long>("ID"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y
                    .GroupBy(a => a.Field<string>("Name"), b => b.Field<string>("Value"))
                    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.FirstOrDefault())
                );


            //Now back to a datatable
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("Col A", typeof(long));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Col B", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Col C", typeof(string));

            foreach(long id in dict.Keys)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> value in dict[id])
                {
                    dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] {id, value.Key, value.Value});
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is another method that may work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(long));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "abc", "mno" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "def", "mnp" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "def", "mnq" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "abc", "mnr" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "abd", "mns" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "abe", "mnt" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "abf", "mnu" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "abc", "mnv" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "ade", "mnw" });


            Dictionary<long, Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>>> dict = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<long>("ID"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y
                    .GroupBy(a => a.Field<string>("Name"), b => b)
                    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.ToList())
                );


            //Now back to a datatable
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();


            foreach(long id in dict.Keys)
            {

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<DataRow>> value in dict[id])
                {
                    dt2.Merge(value.Value.CopyToDataTable());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is close to what i'm looking for I think, but there is no datatable. Basically the incoming data is also in Dictionary long, Dictionary string, string format. Really the first long key is extra data for this portion. But the list of dictionaries can be hundreds of thousands items deep... so I dont think there is really an efficient way to convert the incoming data out of dictionary long, dictionary string, string format to a dt. since its not a DT, from my understanding, there is no x.Field because x isnt a datarow i think.

Comment: I updated code to take the dictionary and put back into a datatable.

Comment: Unfortunately both examples work with a datatable as the datasource, and the incoming data is in the format of List<object>  with the object having a property thats a dictionary<long,dictionary<string,string>> format. That list can be hundreds of thousands, and rarely into the low million(s) deep, and iterating through once is process intensive enough, so transforming it all into a datatable first when it doesnt need to be a datatable further down the line isnt really desirable. I'm having trouble figuring out how to work with the object/dictionaries inside the linq statement.

Comment: I just started with the datatable to generate a Dictionary like your input.  You only need to go from the dictionary to the datatable.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort! We ended up pursuing a different route, but I am accepting this answer because it did answer most of the question.